# KineticJS - Multiple transforms applied serially

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm using KineticJS to allow users to manipulate their images -- crop, rotate, scale, flip, etc.

When I apply any transform to the image, it works great.  But when I apply a second transform it acts upon the original, untransformed image, not my new one.

Here's a simplified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdWPj/  Click the Scale button twice - It should keep increasing the size.  Click the rotate button twice, it should keep the image onscreen.

I know why this is happening. It's because the transforms aren't changing the actual image, they're just changing the way I see that image. But I want it to change the actual image.  Maybe I can save the image after each transform or flatten the stage?

How can I get it to do multiple transforms serially?

Here's the code from the Fiddle:

HTML:

```
<button id="scale">Scale</button>
<button id="rotate">Rotate photo</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var photoPath = "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg";
var stage;
var photo;
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    id: "imageLayer"
});
var originalImage = new Image();
originalImage.src = photoPath;
originalImage.onload = function () {
    photo = new Kinetic.Image({
        id: "image",
        image: originalImage
    });
    stage.setHeight(originalImage.height);
    stage.setWidth(originalImage.width);
    layer.add(photo);
    stage.add(layer);
};
var scale = function () {
    var image = stage.get('#image')[0];
    var scale = 1.5;
    image.setScale(scale, scale);
    stage.draw();
};
var rotate = function () {
    var angle = 90;
    var image = stage.get('#image')[0];
    image.rotateDeg(angle);
    image.setX(image.getHeight());
    stage.draw();
};
document.getElementById('scale').addEventListener('click', scale, false);
document.getElementById('rotate').addEventListener('click', rotate, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edited: Much Simpler Answer! ]**

You can tranform a Kinetic element **relative to it’s current position** (instead of its beginning position)

Here's how:

```
// translate from its current position
rect.move(10,0); 
layer.draw();

// rotate from its current angle
rect.rotate(20*Math.PI/180); 
layer.draw(); 

// scale from its current size
rect.setScaleX(rect.getScaleX()*1.1);
rect.setScaleY(rect.getScaleY()*1.1);
layer.draw();
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Z6Yg8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
      name:"rect1",
      x: 80,
      y: 80,
      width: 50,
      height: 20,
      offset:[50/2,20/2],
      fill: "lightgray",
      stroke: "skyblue",
      strokeWidth: 3
    });
    layer.add(rect);
    stage.draw();


    $("#translate").click(function(){ 
        rect.move(10,0); 
        layer.draw();
    });

    $("#rotate").click(function(){ 
        rect.rotate(20*Math.PI/180); 
        layer.draw(); 
    });

    $("#scale").click(function(){
        rect.setScaleX(rect.getScaleX()*1.1);
        rect.setScaleY(rect.getScaleY()*1.1);
        layer.draw(); 
    });

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="translate">TranslateX +25 </button>
    <button id="rotate">Rotate +5degrees</button>
    <button id="scale">Scale *1.10</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @markE, great design pattern but it didn't solve the problem which is when the transforms stack, they're stacking against the original image. What we need to do is 'flatten' the image after every transform.  How do I re-set the image each time?